# Stata: renaming variables

Tags: rename, stata

I have many variables like:

```
slsoke slsoke_g jfue jfue_g iii iii_g bsueo bsueo_g ...
```

And also there are other variables that don't have the pair, such as hid, pid,...

I have to drop the variables that do not end with _g, and rename the "_g" variables to those without _g. So, for example, the values for "slsoke" should be obsolete, and the "slsoke" should be the exact copy of the "slsoke_g". How can I write a code to do the alterations in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably write something like this:

```
// example

clear
set obs 50
gen hid = _n
gen pid = floor(_n/5)
local y = "slsoke jfue iii bsueo"
foreach x of local y {
    gen `x' = runiform()
    gen `x'_g = int(10 * `x')
}

// the code

local k ""

qui d, varl
local l = r(varlist)
foreach x of local l {
    cap qui replace `x' = `x'_g
    if !_rc local k = "`k' `x'"
}

di as err "`k'"
keep `k'

// bye
```

There might be a shorter solution with an intelligent regex.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you, Fr. Finally, the hid, pid variables are dropped. I will figure out how to keep those two variables by buiding upon your solution.

Comment: Statements of the form `local` macname `= "`<string>`"` will bite you if they are long. Use `local` macname `"`<string>`"` instead. See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0045 for the full story.

Comment: Losing `hid`, `pid`, etc. should not apply with my solution, which works only on pairs of variables, one with and one without your suffix.

Comment: @Nick: Sorry, but I don't know how to modify the original Fr.'s solution. I think I can just drop the *_g variables after the alterations are made, ignoring the last two lines of Fr.'s code.

Comment: Nick is correct, and I have actually read that SJ article, so I should have been careful about the equal sign. I wondered about it when writing the example but could not remember which one was best. Bill: there's indeed more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The most difficult thing here is getting prefixes for all the variable names ending in `_g`. That could be done like this:

```
unab which : *_g 
local which : subinstr local which "_g " " ", all
```

The details are crucial. You are looking for `_g` at the end of a name, hence the extra space, but you need to replace the space too. Now you can cycle over that set of prefixes:

```
foreach w of local which { 
     drop `w'_g 
     rename `w' `w'_g 
}
```

(LATER EDIT) Perhaps you want something more like this.

```
foreach w of local which { 
    replace `w' = `w'_g 
    drop `w'_g 
    rename `w' `w'_g 
}
```

Whatever you want, as said earlier, getting the prefixes seems the most difficult bit, and the rest is a loop over the prefixes.